# Global chunk in bookdown K-M approach

Tags: r, bookdown

I am using the [K-M approach](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/new-session.html) in `bookdown`, so each chapter starts with a clean slate when compiled separately. However, I do want some common code (library, loading of larger data sets) to be available globally.

To work on single chapters, I can include the common code with [include_before_script](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/configuration.html), but this implies that on building the whole book the code is executed multiple times, which is time-consuming.

How can I do an "include_before_build" equivalent?

Comment: Using cache won't work?

Comment: I have not even tried. After too many accidents with cache, we always switch it off globally. No bug in cache, it's just the way any caching works is risky.